# Can DBAN be run on Sun Ultra systems?

Tags: hard-drive, wipe, dban

I'm working with a Sun Microsystems Ultra 10 and want to wipe the contents of it's hard drive. I have a Rescue CD with DBAN on it but the computer won't boot to it. Why not? Can I make it? I'm completely unfamiliar with this, all computers have a BIOS right? So in theory I could tell it to boot from the CD-ROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBAN looks to be designed for x86 computers using a BIOS.

An [Ultra 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra_5/10) is neither of these, being an UltraSPARC computer using OpenBOOT.

You need a Solaris bootable media (commonly a CD) to wipe your disk.

Comment: What does CPU architecture have to do with the ability to read a disk? I didn't know there were alternatives to a BIOS.

Comment: The CPU architecture has a lot to do with the ability to execute binary code a bootable media like DBAN contains.